# unrecognized selector sent to instance when i call from another class

Tags: swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

When i call a recognizer from another class this error appears:
**unrecognized selector sent to instance**,
if you call no error in the same class

```
var orderViewCard = OrderVC()

let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(orderViewCard.handleCardTap(recognzier:)))
orderViewCard.handleArea.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
```

in OrderVC:

```
@objc
    func handleCardTap(recognzier:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        switch recognzier.state {
        case .ended:
            animateTransitionIfNeeded(state: nextState, duration: 0.9)
        default:
            break
        }
}
```

Comment: It makes no sense to assign `self` to `target` if it's supposed to be called in another class.

Comment: put nil or something else?

Comment: yeah, it works, thanks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is to select target accordingly

```
     var orderViewCard = OrderVC()

    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: orderViewCard, action: #selector(orderViewCard.handleCardTap))
    orderViewCard.handleArea.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
```